# Excel formula adding column IDs

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to get an excel formula to auto generate a label into column B that is based off of numbers in column A. I will have duplicate rows under the same number but I need to label them differently, hence the A, B,C on the end of the label in column B. Currently, I have to do this process by hand and it can be upwards of 500+ so anything would really help out.

[image: Excel screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIF() to count and CHAR to change that to a character.

```
=A1&"-Comp-"&CHAR(64+COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1))
```

[image]

One note:  This will only work for the first 26 duplicates after that you will get some weird characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't had a duplicate go past 26 yet so it should be fine.

Comment: Excellent: I was working on this answer myself when your answer appeared.